Problem with python server cert? - "There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed."
This command suddenly started failing on my centos image: RUN pip install --upgrade 'pip==20.3.4'.
This is the error message: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
Did python server allow their cert to lapse, isnt maintaining it anymore, or removed it because centos7 is reaching EOL? Anyone got more context on this situation?
The command works with the --trusted-host pypi.python.org argument, but that's simply bypassing the cert check.

The certificate on that site was just renewed and is valid until May 2025.  You might try it again.  You aren't really running Python 2.7, are you?  Support for that was dropped years ago.

Also try udating the ceritif library first: pip install --upgrade certifi
